# bootstrap.phpを触った覚えがないのにエラーがでる

Tags: php, fuelphp

触った覚えのない箇所でエラーが出ました。

下記のように、bootstrap.phpの66行目でエラーが出ました。

何が原因なのでしょうか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーログ

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::shutdown_handler() in /Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php:66 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}() #1 {main} thrown in /Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 66
        致命的なエラー：未知のエラー：/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php:66で未定義のメソッドError :: shutdown_handler（）を呼び出すスタックトレース：＃0 [internal function]：{closure}（） ＃1 {main}は/Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 66でスローされました
```

下記bootstrap.php

```
        \Cli::error("Error: ".$e->getMessage()." in ".$e->getFile()." on ".$e->getLine());
            \Cli::beep();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return \Error::shutdown_handler();  ←ここ
});

set_exception_handler(function (\Exception $e)
{
    // reset the autoloader
    \Autoloader::_reset();

    // deal with PHP bugs #42098/#54054
    if ( ! class_exists('Error'))
    {
        include COREPATH.'classes/error.php';
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\Error', 'Error');
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException', 'PhpErrorException');
    }
```

82行目も

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::exception_handler() in /Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php:82 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(ReflectionException)) #1 {main} thrown in /Users/■■■■/Desktop/fuelphp/fuel/core/bootstrap.php on line 82
```

Comment: お使いのfuelphpのバージョン情報を記載いただけますか？また環境のPHPのバージョンもお願いします。

Comment: PHP 7.1.16でFuelphpga1.7.0です

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuelphp1.7系はPHP5系でしか使えないようです。PHP7系で使いたいならば1.8以降を利用しましょう。

https://github.com/fuel/core/wiki/Changelog-v1.8.1

> The code has been scanned for new warnings emitted by PHP 7.1.

おそらく発生しているエラーはPHP7系から標準で宣言されるようになったクラスとfuelphpで宣言しているクラス名がかぶってしまっているから起こるエラーです。